# VBScript FileSystemObject.CopyFile() to remote computer Path Not Found

Tags: vbscript, remote-access, filesystemobject, file-copying

Here's a simple script that I can't get to work the way I want it to:

```
Const Overwrite = True
remoteHost = "DESKTOP1"
sDestination = "\\" & remoteHost & "\C:\Users\betsy\Desktop\"
sSource = ".transferFile.txt"

Wscript.Sleep 2000

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
objFSO.CopyFile sSource ,sDestination, Overwrite

msgbox "The file sent: " & sDestination & "."
```

This gives me `Path not found`. Very confusing. Why wouldn't it give me a `Permissions Denied` instead? When I actually sit at Betsy's computer, the path is exactly `C:\Users\betsy\Desktop\`. This path absolutely **does** exist on the remote computer - I've checked it 100 times. Maybe my `sDestination` string is not formatted correctly?

It works when I change sDestination to this...

```
sDestination = "\\" & remoteHost & "\Desktop1-Share\"
```

... but it's not in the correct place.

P.S. `\\DESKTOP1\Desktop1-Share\` is a shared folder configured on the remote computer but I need to send the file to my cow Betsy's desktop folder `\\DESKTOP1\c:\Users\betsy\Desktop`, hopefully without configuring shared-folders.

The whole point of this script is to copy a file to 1 or more remote computers without having to physically sit at them. I have literally hundreds of computers to do this to but only need to prove to myself it can be done to at least one remote computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried

`sDestination = "\\" & remoteHost & "\Users\betsy\Desktop\"`

Comment: This should work in Vista+. The one running the script should be connected to the share as `betsy` or an administrator to see the `\betsy` folder.

Answer (score 3):

The path `\\<hostname>\C:\Users\betsy\Desktop\` is not valid. The part after the hostname should either be `C$` (the automatically created [administrative share](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Administrative_share), only accessible to administrators), or it should be a completely different name and/or path if you've manually shared the destination folder or its ancestor under one.

The above will work in XP. In Vista+, [access to administrative shares is prohibited by default unless the machine is in a domain and the user is a domain admin](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/951016). It [can be re-enabled by hand](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/enable-mapping-to-hostnamec-share-on-windows-vista/) but

- using the new `Users` share as suggested in [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40325087/648265) is a more manageable way. Under it, an accessing user will only see profiles and folders in them that [the owner chose to share with them](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb727037.aspx#EDAA) (technically, for which they have read&execute permissions).

Comment: I tried changing from c: to c$ but I had the same error. I took the C out completely and it works now. Thanks for looking into this though.

Comment: @Rhyknowscerious Oh, I see, [they disabled access to administrative shares in Vista+ unless it's in a domain and the user is a domain admin](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/951016).

Comment: Those are very helpful links. I read them all and I'm sure they'll help me avoid a lot of confusion in the near future, dealing with permission issues and hidden administrative network shares. Thanks a lot.